# Typing List.nil

Tags: lean4, errors

I'm working my way through [Functional Programming in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/getting-to-know/polymorphism.html) and there's an exercise to create  a `zip` function for combining two `List`s into a single list of `Pair`s.

My initial implementation fails to type-check because Lean doesn't know what Type to give `[]`. I don't understand why, as it's specified in the function signature. Here was my initial implementation:

```
def zip : (as: List α) → (bs: List β) → List (α × β)
    | a::arest, b::brest => (a, b) :: (zip arest brest)
    | _ => []
```

And the error it generated:

```
type mismatch
  []
has type
  List ?m.16818 : Type ?u.16817
but is expected to have type
  List β → List (α × β) : Type (max ?u.16734 ?u.16738)
```

I figured that the the right way to fix this would be to use the constructor `List.nil` with an explicit parameter for the type. The source for `List` starts with `inductive List (α : Type u)`, so I figured I should set the $\alpha$ parameter like so:

```
def zip : (as: List α) → (bs: List β) → List (α × β)
    | a::arest, b::brest => (a, b) :: (zip arest brest)
    | _ => List.nil (α := α×β)
```

However, this fails with another error:

```
type mismatch
  []
has type
  List (α × β) : Type (max ?u.16738 ?u.16734)
but is expected to have type
  List β → List (α × β) : Type (max ?u.16734 ?u.16738)
```

This is confusing to me because I expect it to return a `List (α × β)`, and when I check the typing of the first branch Lean tells me that it has this type. So why is Lean expecting a `List β → List (α × β)` for the second branch? And is there any way to get Lean to figure out the correct type for the more idiomatic `[]` automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a pattern for the second argument, ie you should have `| _, _ => …` instead of `| _ => …` in your second branch. The error that Lean reports stems from the fact that since it is only given a pattern for the argument of type `List α`, it is still waiting for an argument of type `List β` in that branch, and so `[]` does not have the right type.

I guess this is a somewhat non-intuitive part of simultaneous pattern-matching, that you still have to provide a pattern for each matched term, even if this pattern is `_`. In other words, `_` is interpreted as a pattern for the *first* matched term only, not for *all of them*.

Comment: Oh interesting, I still had this idea of simultaneous matches being `Pair`s in my mind. A single `_` would work in Python because no unpacking would be triggered and the entire tuple would be assigned to it.

Comment: It's also interesting, and didn't even occur to me previously, that each branch of the match can use a different number of simultaneous matches (1 or more; is 0 possible as a base case?).